# UI Datepicker range. iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, datepicker, range

I have a datePickerView which I want it to have a min date = current time, max date = 48hrs later. It's currently working fine, as I can't pick out of that range. But there's some aesthetic problems. Some of the period in that range is not in black. For example in the picture below, today's 7hour hand is suppose to be in black but its not.

[image: pic]

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{

[super viewDidLoad];
NSDate *now = [[NSDate alloc] init];
NSLog(@"now is %@", now);
[datepick setDate:now animated:YES];
[now release];
datepick.minimumDate = now;

NSDate *todaysDate = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[dateComponents setHour:48];
NSDate *targetDate = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:dateComponents toDate:todaysDate  options:0];
[dateComponents release];
[gregorian release];
datepick.maximumDate = targetDate;
NSLog(@"targetDate is %@", targetDate);


}
```

Comment: No solution for that one. Its not bold/black because today 6:35 have passed since ur current time is 6:37

Comment: as you can see, the 7 on the hour hand is also not bolded.

Comment: thats because the time 7:xx AM is not valid. The picker doesnt know if ur going to select an am time or pm time so its keeping all hour numbers grey

Comment: Anyone have a solution to this problem?

Comment: Nops. Only that you do not set a minimum date to your picker but check the date once user has selected it to filter out those that have already passed

Answer (score 1):

This is default behavior when you set a minimum date and a maximum date and APPLE does it clearly to make it obvious that they are not selectable.

What you can do is implement a `UIPickerView` for the dates and implement `viewForRow` for the pickerView methods.

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view{
UILabel* tView = (UILabel*)view;
if (!tView){
    tView = [[UILabel alloc] init];

    // Add label.text which is the picker value for the row (for that component)

    // set the font for the label as black.

}
```

You can also change the font size of the values in the pickerView.