# How to set time range in a day using UIDatePickerView

Tags: iphone

I am using UIDatePickerView, just like we can set the date range using "maximumDate" and "minimumDate", is there any way to set time range in a day like from 9.00 am to 6.00 pm ?

Answer (score 0):

Not really. `minimumDate` and `maximumDate` can include a time of day (`NSDate` is more like a timestamp than a calendar date), but this only has an effect if they are both on the same day because otherwise all (clock) times are possible within the date range.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you should set the time using these two as well. NSDate objects have both date and time components. You should do something like this:

```
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];

//set the date using setDate: setMonth: setYear:
[dateComponents setHour:9];    //setHour:18 for maximumDate

NSDate *targetDate = [gregorian dateFromComponents::dateComponents];
[dateComponents release];
[gregorian release];
datepick.minimumDate = targetDate;
```

If that doesnt help, have a look at these Qs:

[UI Datepicker range. iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857697/ui-datepicker-range-iphone)

[How to set time on NSDate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7288671/nsdate-set-time)