# Set Time Range on UIDatePicker

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uidatepicker

I have a `UIDatePicker` that I have programmatically added into my code, I'm now looking to see if I can somehow set a range on the time. So that the user can only select a date, and a time between the hours of 09:00 and 17:30. Any other options would ideally not show up. Is there a way I can add this into my UIDatePicker code?

Here is my code:

```
CGRect pickerFrame = CGRectMake(0,250,0,0);

UIDatePicker *myPicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:pickerFrame];
[myPicker addTarget:self action:@selector(pickerChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[self.view addSubview:myPicker];
```

Comment: You can not select the options other than the range you set.Hope this will work:
[Check the link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857697/ui-datepicker-range-iphone)

Comment: Just set the `minimumDate` and `maximumDate` properties.

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16322437/how-to-set-minimum-time-to-appear-as-default-in-uidatepicker-everytime

Comment: @Luke please remember to accept an answer if it is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this :-

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[comps setYear:10];
NSDate *maxDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:currentDate options:0];
[comps setYear:-10];
NSDate *minDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:currentDate options:0];    
[yourdatePicker setMaximumDate:maxDate];
[yourdatePicker setMinimumDate:minDate];
```

Answer (score 2):

`UIDatePicker` has properties for `minimumDate` and `maximumDate`.

You should get used to reading the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDatePicker_Class/Reference/UIDatePicker.html).

Normally just sticking the class name into google the first result will be the Apple documentation.